# Result of ls -la in adb shell

Tags: adb, selinux

If I go into my unrooted phone's adb shell (Samsung galaxy s7 Android 8) I get a result similar to this:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 921 root   root         0 2020-01-26 10:06 acct
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root       225 1970-01-01 09:00 android.hardware.drm@1.0-service.widevine.rc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root     45121 1970-01-01 09:00 audit_filter_table
```

Notice that there is no . after the file permissions (eg: dr-xr-xr-x). If I type getenforce I get

```
enforcing
```

so SELinux is enforced. Then why doesn't ls show a . after the file permissions? Has it always been this way in android? As far as I know, in Centos ls result will show a . after file permissions if SELinux is installed and enforced/permissive. Does android behave differently in this regard?

Comment: It depends which `ls` binary you are using. Android's default `toybox ls` is minimal. So is `busybox ls`. I use full `coreutils ls` which does show dot `.`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif is this something extra I need to install? Or something that needs root?

Comment: `coreutils` like `util-linux` is kinda standard package every Linux distro has installed. You can build for your device. I have built for `aarch64`. If you need I can share link.

Comment: @IrfanLatif so I need to compile it myself? It's not like an apk file we can install?

Comment: Termux is there already. But Linux packages there are modified for Android environment. So may not behave as you expect on a Linux distro.